# Can I use const_cast on a copy of a pointer?

Tags: c++, constants

Is there undefined behavior here?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string str = "Hello";

    auto p = str.c_str();
    char x[] = "sup";

    const_cast<char*&>(p) = x;
}
```

Comment: No, it still points to non-modifiable memory. If you're after `std::string` editing, you can safely use `&str[0]` in C++11.

Comment: Does it matter? The `const_cast` is quite pointless there since `p = x;` is perfectly fine...

Comment: @chris: It does not point to 'const' memory

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas, Not here, no, but for the question in the title, it doesn't matter whether it's a copy or not. I'm not exactly sure why the question doesn't match up with the code that well, but that's what I first thought of when I read it.

Answer (score 0):

No, only casting away constness of an inherently const object and modifying it gives you UB not otherwise.